# Executar um aggregate usando arrays de dicionários no pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Atualmente tenho a seguinte estrutura de Documento (Mongodb):

[document mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeQ1x.png)

Criei uma função para realizar algumas ações com agregates (match e project) e está funcionando.

```py
def aggregate(self, collection):
        return collection.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$and": [
                            {
                                "route.origin": {"$eq": "x"},
                                "route.destination": {"$eq": "y"},
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "route.origin": 1,
                        "route.destination": 1,
                        "route.dates": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$route.dates",
                                "as": "dates",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$and":[
                                    {"$gte": ["$$dates.date","2022-02-05"]}    
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    }
                },
            ]
        )
```

Hoje tenho como saída desse método a seguinte configuração:

```py
[
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('63e3b60983b280e50089be64'), 
        'route': {
            'origin': 'x', 
            'destination': 'y', 
            'dates': [
                {
                    'date': '2022-02-05', 
                    'departures': [
                        {
                            'origin': 'x_', 
                            'destination': 'y_', 
                            'hour': '09: 00', 
                            'busclass': 'convencional', #Quero manter essa departure
                            'company': 'Company x', 
                            'source': 'Source y', 
                            'available_seats': 12, 
                            'price': Decimal128('267.2'), 
                            'created_at': datetime.datetime(2023,2,7,2,0)
                        },
                        {
                            'origin': 'x_', 
                            'destination': 'y_', 
                            'hour': '09: 00', 
                            'busclass': 'Não necessária', #Remover essa departure
                            'company': 'Company x', 
                            'source': 'Source y', 
                            'available_seats': 12, 
                            'price': Decimal128('267.2'), 
                            'created_at': datetime.datetime(2023,2,7,2,0)
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

A minha dificuldade é encontrar um **Agregate Project** que também retorne somente itens dentro da departure com busclass que eu escolher.

Obs: estava olhando a seguinte documentação [aqui](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) mas não encontrei algo mais complexo.

Comment: Evite o uso de imagens desnecessárias. Poste o JSON da estrutura de documento que você mencionou.

Answer (score -2):

Fiz a query no quer precisa ter de retorno mesmo que dentro o array departures.busclass tenha 1 verdadeiro. espero que ajude :

```
db.collect.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "route.origin": { "$eq": "x" },
                "route.destination": { "$eq": "y" },
            }],
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        route: {
            "origin": '$route.origin',
            "destination": '$route.destination',
            dates: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        result: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$route.dates",
                                as: "d",
                                in: {
                                    $cond: [{ $gte: [{ "$toDate": "$$d.date" }, { "$toDate": "2022-02-05" }] }, {
                                        $arrayElemAt: ['$$d.departures', { $indexOfArray: ['$$d.departures.busclass', 'convencional'] }]
                                    }, '$$REMOVE']
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$$result",
                            as: "item",
                            cond: {
                                $ifNull: ['$$item', "$$REMOVE"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $size: '$route.dates' }, 0] },  "$$PRUNE", "$$KEEP"]
    }
}])
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu usei essa sua base e conseguir resolver meu problema.